# Google Play Store Internal Test cannot start roll out

Tags: android, testing, google-play, beta

I am going to start rolling out the first version of the application to the internal testers.

But the button `START ROLLOUT TO INTERNAL TEST` is disabled and I cannot see any other error messages or warnings here.

Can anyone let me know what's going?
[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBJAX.png)

Comment: I have the same issue and the answer below is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Have you filled out all required data under the things with gray check boxes? All 4 checkmark icons should be green and if you hover over a gray one it will pop up what is remaining *e.g upload icons, feature graphic, etc.*

[image: things to fill out]

Comment: Ashamed to admit, this indeed was the problem

Comment: @comodoro don't be ashamed. Google gives us no information on this whatsoever! How are we supposed to know that we need to make all these green? It's my first android app and I'm disappointed how difficult Google is making this.

Comment: Thanks a mil! I had the same problem, I didn't have a clue that everything needs to be green even for internal test rollouts. Gahh.

Comment: it's a huge burden to set your store listing up before being able to release an internal test

Comment: I'm sure there may be more things that could go wrong, but this fixed it for me, too.  I know Google likes to make their UI's sparse, but it wouldn't hurt to add a note about this.

Comment: It makes no sense to have to fill out those things for "Internal Testing" only, but unfortunately that's the way.

Comment: This is exactly the solution for my problem!! Thanks!

Comment: I confirm, in my case I needed to complete even the Store Listing with screenshot, and I just needed to submit my app for an internal review.

Comment: I can confirm that overlooking the Pricing & distribution section was what was preventing my submission to internal testing.

If you are using the the new beta version of the console then you don't even get the grey ticks as a visual clue. I had to return to the old version of the console to check whether this was the problem and fix it there.

Really bad UX here.

I can also confirm that my account is only 8 days old. This doesn't completely disconfirm the observation in this threads other answer, but I do strongly suggest you attempt to follow this one before deciding to wait it out.

Comment: Seconding @JoeSinfield - go back to classic console for now. The new UI is unfinished and even more uninformative than the old one.

Comment: They should've made it so we could skip all these graphics in Internal Testing. Like come on!

Answer (score 9):

For those who may be coming to this question later, this button may be disabled if you recently signed up for new Google Play developer account.

You might be seeing a message like this:
[image]

This is due to a change by Google to keep bad developers out of the store. ([an article](https://www.helpnetsecurity.com/2019/04/19/google-play-protection/))

This can be the case even though you're ready to roll out the changes.
[image]

Comment: I believe this answer is wrong, and actually caused me to lose a whole week of waiting in vain. After re-reading [Google's explanation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282), I realized that It hadn't been submitted for review. Once I completed the steps outlined in the accepted answer to the OP, the "Start Rollout" button became enabled, and after clicking it, the status of my app on the dashboard changed to  "Pending publication", meaning now it has been submitted, and should hopefully take less than 3 days to have it approved

Comment: You still have to fill out the required information Google requests for any type of rollout. My experience was that even after filling out all of the required information (which I did immediately after creating my developer account), there was still a vague message about Google reviewing my app submission. My guess is that your one week delay was long enough to keep you from the new account delay. So once you had all of the required fields filled you could begin to rollout your app right away.

Comment: Interesting. Indeed my account is a few months old, so you may be right. Although that would be unfair of Google not to display the real reason you can't submit the app - that your account is too new - and instead show the same message that it shows when your account has already passed the delay. Also,  what would be the purpose of delaying your submitting the app for review? If other developers have experienced the same delay, it might be worthwhile to demand an explanation from them.

Comment: In my case, the button are enabled after published a first "production" release for review.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like filling out all the fields is a requirement per the step 3 of the following page to rollout any release:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?hl=en