# Apk not optimized

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, apk, publish

I have an app developed using Cordova. I generated a final APK for the release version (already aligned and signed), but when I upload my APK in Google Play console, I receive the following error message explaining that my APK isn't optimized, preventing the publishing procedure.

APK NOT OPTIMIZED

This APK includes features and unused codes that are sent to users. Your app would be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. When the app is not optimized for device settings, the download and installation size is larger than necessary. Larger apps have lower installation fees and take up space on users' devices.

How can I get around or fix this error to publish my app?

Answer (score 1):

Try this please :

1. Go to Build > Generate Sign Bundle
2. Complete Signing info
3. Upload de .aab file generated in /platforms/android/outputs/

Answer (score 0):

[solved]
Published my app without using Android app bundle. No needs to correct this warning for publishing.

Comment: yes but this is not a solution to the problem you faced.

Comment: you just need to solve every other section as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444424/google-play-store-internal-test-cannot-start-roll-out)